Why is this AC motor wired like this?
Follow-up to How to rewire this dual-voltage AC motor? and my self-discovered answer:

Either way, each of the three windings gets 115V and the correct relative polarity, so it ought to work the same way regardless.  (provided that the correct voltage is used for the way it's wired!)  But I still have some questions about the design:

Why use an additional wire (Red) from the switch to the motor, and a 3-pole switch?  Why not use a 2-pole switch, and permanently connect the capacitor to the end of the lower main winding (connect T4 and T5) at the motor?
For 115V, why does the starting circuit and lower main winding tap off of the middle of the Overload, instead of being exactly in parallel with the upper main winding?  What purpose does that serve?
Why does the manual that I found say, "115 volt operation of this tool is not recommended!", despite showing how to do it?  Is it entirely because it's operating at 14 amps instead of 7, and the switch, overload protection, and most of the wiring have to handle that?  Or is there something else going on too?
How does the start capacitor cut-out actually work?  The relay coil is exactly across the start winding, and the contacts are normally closed.  So far so good, but as soon as power is applied, there's 115V there (minus the capacitor's reactance), so wouldn't the relay activate and drop out the starter right away?  I can understand the motor also being a generator for this purpose, to keep the relay energized and the contacts open (or the windings form a parasitic transformer that does the same job), but I can't quite imagine a workable starting sequence.

Maybe there's some phase interactions going on, so that the total voltage stays low enough to not activate it until it's reached a certain speed?
Maybe it does drop out right away, but the time it takes to do that already has the motor running the right direction?  (so if you stall it and let it go, it could go backwards)




Possible answer for #2, but still stumped on the rest:
My KiCad library doesn't have the symbol that the manual uses, so I fudged it with what I do have.  The actual (screenshotted) symbol is:

As I drew it in KiCad, the pin numbers are the same, if you ignore pin 4 that doesn't exist externally.
Thus, I suspect it's actually a heater and a thermal disconnect, and not two different kinds of circuit protection.  The combination is designed for 7 amps through the heater, and so the 115V wiring that draws 14A overall, has to keep that 7A through the heater while the contacts still break everything.
